# Passing a property as argument like a delegate in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, properties

I know it's possible to pass a `Function` or a `Sub` using `AddressOf` to pass a `Delegate`, like in a `ThreadStart` definition.

```
Dim oThStart as new System.Threading.Thread.ThreadStart(AddressOf MySub)
```

Now I have this program in which I do the same processing over and over, but on differents properties of the same object. This is a part of the code I have. I only show two iterations, but there are nine in total and there are other processing I didn't include yet so it will get bigger.

```
If _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Column = "" Then
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Column = oColumn.ColumnName
    GetHeader(ColInfoStr1, _oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Numeric = boolIsNumeric
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Float = boolIsFloat
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoDefaultStr1 = GetDefault(ColInfoStr1, _oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)

ElseIf _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Column = "" Then
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Column = oColumn.ColumnName
    GetHeader(ColInfoStr2, _oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Numeric = boolIsNumeric
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Float = boolIsFloat
    _oInfoRefBase.InfoDefaultStr2 = GetDefault(ColInfoStr2, _oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)
End If
```

What I would like to is to define a new function `GetOtherInfo()` that I could call to fill the properties I want, which depend of the iteration. Something like

```
GetOtherInfo(_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Numeric,_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1Float,_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr1NotNull,boolIsNumeric,boolIsFloat,ColInfoStr1,_oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)
```

OR

```
GetOtherInfo(_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Numeric,_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2Float,_oInfoRefBase.InfoStr2NotNull,boolIsNumeric,boolIsFloat,ColInfoStr2,_oInfoTable.NomTable, oColumn.ColumnName)
```

And so on. I know this syntax isn't the right one as I send the value of my property, but I would like to send it so that I can change it. Some properties a validation in the set if that makes a differences.

Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: It sounds like this Column/Numeric/Float combination with different numbers prefixed ought to be a separate Class with the Column/Numeric/Float as properties hanging off of it. Then you'd just have an `InfoStr1` property containing one of those objects, and `InfoStr2` property containing one, etc. And there's no difficulty passing an object to another method and letting it set the properties on that object.

Comment: Have you tried making use of `ByRef` in `GetOtherInfo()`? Per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2010/01/26/the-many-cases-of-byref.aspx, this may be possible (and it looks like it is implemented as a pass-by-proxy scheme).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. you may want to use System.Reflection.PropertyInfo which has GetValue and SetValue methods to Get/Set a proeprty. And also, to make life easier, you may also want to wrap up some procedures to get property info easily.

pseudocode

```
Function GetPropertyInfo(Of T As Class)(obj As T, propertyFunc As Func(Of T, Object)) As System.Reflection.PropertyInfo
    ' implement using reflection or expression trees
End Function

' Sample usage:

Sub Test()
    ' Copy value from obj1.Name to obj2.Description
    Dim obj1 = New ClassA()
    Dim source = GetPropertyInfo(obj1, Function(t As ClassA) t.Name)

    Dim obj2 = New ClassB()
    Dim target = GetPropertyInfo(obj2, Function(t As ClassB) t.Description)

    target.SetValue(obj2, source.GetValue)
End Sub
```

and be careful with reflection: the performance is not that good. So to work around this, try to use some expression trees to build up some fast property wrappers - believe there are plenty of resources on the net for that.

one for example - http://geekswithblogs.net/Madman/archive/2008/06/27/faster-reflection-using-expression-trees.aspx

Comment: Nevermind then. I just wanted to prevent using similars copies of the same code because it's cleaner, but I won't sacrifice performance for that.

Comment: fully understand your concern. you might give a try to use expression tree to wrap around - it has very very minor overhead as per our testing: we had similar issues before and eventually we used expression trees to wrap reflections and the performance is very good too.

Comment: Beware, VB will wrap your lambda in a "Convert", in contrast to C# which will pass it through unmolested.  In C#, the expression that results from e.g. the first lambda is t => t.Name.  In VB, it's t => Convert(t.Name).  To handle the latter, you need to check the node type of the body of your expression (it will be ExpressionType.Convert), cast the body to UnaryExpression, then cast the body's Operand to MemberExpression (whew!).  Vs. simply casting the body to MemberExpression in the C# case.